# Symbolic link to folder on another device

Tags: symlink

If I have a symbolic link in a directory on a physical drive that points to tmpfs RAM partition, and I write to the symbolic link will the physical experience an writing?

I'm going to being down a large amount of data writes and I want it in RAM instead of taxing my SSD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there will only be physical reading of the link target from the SSD. Then the writing will go to RAM.